# Android Firebase: Save data to database

Tags: java, android, json, firebase

I am trying to save and retrieve data from Firebase but I am having a little trouble getting the right syntax.

Users register through the Authentication method of email and password and login using the same details.

I have two edit text field that asks for an input of name and the statement. There is a button below the two edit text box that is meant to save the data to the database.

```
private void saveQuote(){
String name = author.getText().toString();
String quotes = quote.getText().toString();

Author author = new Author(name, quotes);
//databaseReference.child(u.getUid()).setValue(author);

if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(name) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(quotes)){
    user = auth.getCurrentUser();
    String userID = user.getUid();
    databaseReference.child(userID).child("quotes").setValue(author);
}else{
    Toast.makeText(this, "Author Name is Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
Toast.makeText(this, "Saved...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

}
The idea is that when a user logs into the app, it will save their Uid as the main tile in the Database, then below that, their should be another section for where the name and statement is saved as one field. This means if they write another name and statement and press save, under their ID it should create a new field with the name and statement written.

```
save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            saveQuote();
        }
    });
```

Firebase Rules:

```
    {
  "rules": {
     "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth !== null && auth.uid === $uid",
        ".write": "auth !== null && auth.uid === $uid"
    }
  }
}
```

What can I do to save each request of save data.

Format wanted:

> UID
>
> > Entry
> >
> > > Name
> > >
> > > Quote
> >
> > Entry2
> >
> > > Name
> > >
> > > Quote

...etc

Comment: Try use .Push(author) instead of .setValue(author)

Comment: Sorry just attempting it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following :

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(userID);
String key = ref.push().getKey();
ref.child(key).child("name").setValue(name);
ref.child(key).child("quote").setValue(quotes);
```

Inside the `saveQuote` method, get an instance of the database and then using `setValue` you can add data to the database

Comment: Im getting an error: It says incompatible type, found FirebaseDatabase, required DatabaseRefrence

Comment: Okay works now, the command was ```atabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(userID);```

Answer (score -1):

You can directly push your `Author` object to database. Try using below:

```
private void saveQuote(){
    String name = author.getText().toString();
    String quotes = quote.getText().toString();

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(name) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(quotes)) {

        Author author = new Author(name, quotes);

        String userID = auth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        String quoteKey = databaseReference.child(userID).push().getKey();

        databaseReference.child(userID).child(quoteKey).setValue(author);

        Toast.makeText(this, "Saved...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Author Name is Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```